# How do i move folders in a batch with wildcards

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, move, directory

I have a bunch of folders named as dates Ex `20132706`, `20132306`, `20132205`, `20133004`.

I want to move these folders to there corresponding folders, and I could just write 1000 lines of this but i want to add wild cards.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
Move \\folder1\20132706  \\folder1\june2013
Move \\folder1\20132306  \\folder1\june2013
Move \\folder1\20132205  \\folder1\May2013
Move \\folder1\20133004  \\folder1\April2013
```

This is what i want to do:

```
Move \\folder1\??????06 \\folder1\june2013
Move \\folder1\??????05 \\folder1\may2013
Move \\folder1\??????04 \\folder1\april2013
```

However I am not succesful in using wildcards.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Windows batch or Linux?

Comment: You will need to research HEAVILY into the `forfiles`, `for /r` and `for /f` commands. All of which are very useful when going into complex batch scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET localroot=u:\folder
FOR /f %%i IN (
  'dir /ad /b "%localroot%" ^|findstr /r "^[0-9]*$"'
 ) DO CALL :movedir %%i

GOTO :EOF

:movedir
:: ensure destination is exactly 8 chars long
SET "dest=%1"
SET dest=%dest:~7%
IF NOT DEFINED dest GOTO :EOF 
SET dest=%dest:~1%
IF DEFINED dest GOTO :EOF

SET "dest=%1"
:: convert month to text
SET "month="
SET "dest="&FOR %%i IN (01 january 02 february 03 march etc etc 12 december) DO IF NOT DEFINED dest (
 IF DEFINED month SET dest=%%i%dest:~0,4%
 IF %dest:~-2%==%%i SET month=Y
)

ECHO MOVE %localroot%\%1 %localroot%\%dest%

GOTO :eof
```

This should do the required job - all you'd need do is change the `localroot` definition, fill out the month list in the indicated format and after checking remove the `ECHO` to activate the `MOVE`.

Loop through the directories, filtering out only those that are pure-numeric (any number of numerics between start and end)

Check that the name is exactly 8 long, convert and reformat the destination name and done!